# Getting error 401 on speech-to-text watson API

Tags: php, curl, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I`m trying to make my php script send a curl request to the speech-to-text API.

I configured the API in the Watson console and mounted the script to send the audio and apikey.

```
$url = 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize';
$file = '@files/WhatsApp Audio 2019-01-25 at 12.17.28 (1).flac';
$fields = array(
'file' => $file,
'continuous' => true
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "apikey:KEY"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: audio/flac')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Transfer-Encoding: chunked'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE, 40000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
$executed = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($executed);
```

I am getting always this result:

string(37) "{"code":401, "error": "Unauthorized"}"

Comment: Hi @Matheus Weber Could you resolve the problem? I have the same problem with a Lite plan (IBM). I'm working in localhost on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

In your script you have `apikey:KEY` as credentials. I know it sounds obvious, but better double checking: have you replaced it with your actual api key from the IBM console? If you are using `KEY` as your key, well, no surprises that you get 401 unauthorized :)

Also notice that your api key is associated to a particular gateway URL, which you can also find it in the same place in the IBM Cloud console where you retrieve the key (see screenshot). And that's the URL you need to use for your curl commands. For example, in my case, since I created the app with location London, the url is gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I changed here to not show my key, I changed the URL to the one showed in IBM Cloud console, but still the same error.

Comment: @MatheusWeber The script works fine for me with right url/key. Where are you running it from?

Comment: I am running on a web hosting from Hostgator.

Comment: Could you resolve the problem? I have the same problem. Lite plan with IBM, I'm working in localhost on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post. I Just want to share code that works for me (18/08/2022).

I had a similar problem like this post, in my case the way I was creating the file path was the problem. But now It works fine, just copy-paste and hit refresh your browser.

Cheers.

---

```
$fname = 'YourFilePath';  //Example: 'C:/audios/audio-file.flac;
$cfile = new CURLFile(realpath($fname));
$file = array ('file' => $cfile); 

$urlx = 'Paste here your url'; //It is something like this: https://api.us-south.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/xxxxxxxxxxx
$curlx = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_URL, $urlx);
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'apikey:PASTE_EXACTLY_HERE_YOUR_API_KEY'); 
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: audio/flac']); 
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file);
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE, 40000);
curl_setopt($curlx, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);
  
$datax = curl_exec($curlx);
curl_close($curlx);
print($datax);
```